# Last inserted record id cannot be retrieved in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, return-value

I'm trying to print last inserted record id of my stripe subscription table.

This is what I have done so far,

```
public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
     
        $user = auth()->user();
        $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;
        $appId = $request->appId;
        $planId = $request->plan;
        $user->newSubscription('main', $planId)->create($paymentMethod);

        $AppPayment = DB::table('subscriptions')->insertGetId();

        return $AppPayment;
        dd($AppPayment);
    
        

       $this->activateApp($appId);
       

    }
```

The record has created but I'm not getting the `dd` output..

Comment: because you have a return statement before `dd`, move `dd` before `return` you will see the dd result. return statement means the method is done, so the last two lines of code will not be executed.

Comment: nope, stll not getting

Comment: which line of code is creating the subscriptions?

Comment: $user->newSubscription('main', $planId)->create($paymentMethod); this

Comment: but here $AppPayment = DB::table('subscriptions')->insertGetId(); it's also trying to create a record, so it's null

Comment: got it, what would be the solution then?

Comment: did you create this method newSubscription?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211264/discussion-between-volka-dimitrev-and-andy-song).

Answer (score 0):

you need to insert record here! This should be the place to insert the record.

```php
    $id = DB::table('subscriptions')->insertGetId(['foo'=>'bar']);

dd($id);
```

***Update***
if you use cashier, check this code.

```php
public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {

        $user = auth()->user();
        $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;
        $appId = $request->appId;
        $planId = $request->plan;
        $subscription = $user->newSubscription('main', $planId)->create($paymentMethod);
        dd($subscription->id);
        return $AppPayment;

       $this->activateApp($appId);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check your data array there is nothing insterting that is why id not getting

```
$dataArray = [
            'column_name' => $request->inputFieldName,
                  ];
$AppPayment = DB::table('subscriptions')->insertGetId($dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work after you create the subscription:

```
$user->subscription->id;
```

Comment: `$user->subscription()->id;` should be `$user->subscription->id;`